# NHibernate QueryOver Where Or on property and nested collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have classes `Foo` and `Bar`

```
class Foo {
    string Name;
    IList<Bar> Bars;
}

class Bar {
    string Name;
}
```

I have an input `q` and I want to write an NHibernate query that returns a list of `Foo` objects if `Foo.Name` contains `q` or any of the `Bars` objects' `Name`s contain `q`.

I know how I can make separate queries but I am not sure how to combine it into 1 with the `OR` operator in between. Basically if a `Foo` object contains `q` in its name or in any of its `Bars` names, I want the `Foo` object to be in the output.

```
this.sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()
    .QueryOver<Foo>()
    .Where(x => x.Name.IsInsensitiveLike(q))
    .List();
```

```
this.sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()
    .QueryOver<Foo>()
    .JoinQueryOver<Bar>(x => x.Bars)
    .Where(x => x.Name.IsInsensitiveLike(q))
    .List();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with declaring aliases, for later use in queries

```
Foo foo = null;
Bar bar = null;
```

The first approach now, is to join collection *(and get a bit ugly results, with multiplied parent for each matching child)*

```
.QueryOver<Foo>(() => foo)
.JoinQueryOver<Bar>(x => x.Occupations, () => bar)
.Where(x => foo.Name.IsInsensitiveLike(q)
         || bar.Name.IsInsensitiveLike(q))
```

This will work, but could return some rows repeating parent `Foo`, in case that there are more matching children `Bar`...

```
Foo1, Bar1
Foo1, Bar2
```

To get clean parent result-set only, we need to replace JOIN with subquery

```
.QueryOver<Foo>(() => foo)
.Where(Restrictions
    .Or(
        Restrictions.Where(() => foo.Name.IsInsensitiveLike(q)),
        Subqueries
            .WhereProperty(() => foo.ID)
                .In(QueryOver.Of<Bar>(() => bar)
                    .Where(() => bar.Name.IsInsensitiveLike(q))
                    .Select(y => bar.Foo.ID)
                )
    )
)
```

*That also expects, that child Bar has back reference to Foo... which is absolutely legal and business domain model supporting.*

Comment: We can just add the `.TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)` to your first suggestion and thus filter out unique parents only. No need to overcomplicate with the second. You can change your answer and I will accept it

Comment: On a second thought, I now understand why you didn't suggest using the `.TransofrmUsing` ... it is doing whatever it is doing on the *client side*, which is problematic for a number of reasons, in my case - pagination, but also performance. If I want to skip 10 rows and get the next 10, and my `foo`s contain more than one `bar` object matching `q`, then I will not be taking 10, but less, since a `foo` will be counted twice, because of the join.